# MySQL: how to update column using value before change

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table with three column: `id, field1, field2`.

And there is a row: `id=1, field1=1, field2=1`.

Run a update SQL: `UPDATE my_table SET field1=field2+1, field2=field1+1 WHERE id=1;`

I expected the result is: id=1, field1=2, field2=2. But in fact I got: id=1, field1=2, field2=3. Because when calculating field2=field1+1, the value of field1 has changed!

I figure out a SQL to solve this problem:

```
UPDATE my_table dest, (SELECT * FROM my_table) src
SET dest.field1=src.field2+1, dest.field2=src.field1+1
WHERE dest.id=1;
```

However I want to insert a record, and if the row was existed then do a update just like above.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, field1, field2) VALUES(1, 1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    field1=field2+1, field2=field1+1;
```

This SQL has problem same as the first SQL. So how can I do this update using the value before change with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't think of anything else but a temp variable. However, couldn't think of a way to make SQL syntax work, other than this:

```
set @temp = 0;
update test.test set 
    f1 = (@temp:=f1), 
    f1 = f2 + 1, 
    f2 = @temp + 1 
where id = 1;
```

Hope this helps, and hope even more it helps you find a better way :)

Comment: Btw, directly swapping two columns using `SET a= b, b=a` is working in every other DBMS, only mysql doesn't follow Standard SQL and skews it up :(

Comment: Temp variable is a good idea! But What's the syntax to use temp variable in `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Answer (score 0):

I find a trick way to do this.

Use the [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) clause to create temp variable. Field update use temp variable to calculate.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, f1, f2) VALUES(1, 1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id=IF((@t1:=f1 & @t2:=f2), 1, 1), f1=@t2+1, f2=@t1+1;
```

There is some point to notice:

1. The performance is a bit slow. Especially copy TEXT value to temp variable.
2. If field id need to use IF clause, the expr will be more complicated like:

   ```
   ((@t1:=f1 & @t2:=f2) || TRUE) AND (Your Condition)
   ```